# Node package dependencies on IBM Cloud Foundry - require/module is not defined (Package not loading)

Tags: node.js, eclipse, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am working on an application via the toolchain tool on IBM Cloud and editing the code via the Eclipse Orion IDE. As I am not accessing this through my local cli, my understanding is that in order to so call `npm install {package}`, I would just need to include the package in the `package.json` file under dependencies and `require` it in my app. However, when I load the application, I get the require is not defined indicating that the package has not been installed. Moreover, the `require()` is being used in the `app.js` file with the application being launched but not from files in my `public` directory.

After playing around further, it seems it might have to do with the way the directory tree is being traced as the error is only thrown in subdirectories. For example, `require('express')` works in `app.js` which is in the main directory `./` but fails when it is called in `test.js` in `./subdirectory/test.js`. I feel like I'm missing something painfully simple like configuration of endpoint or something.

I've been searching around but I can't seem to find how to get the packages loaded, preferably without using the cli. Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Update: After playing around further, I am also getting module is not defined error when trying to require from another file in the same directory. For example `module.exports = 'str'` returns this error. While trying to `require('./file')` returns the require is not defined. It might have to do with how node is wrapping the functions?

Update 2: Tried `"start": "npm install && node app.js"` in `package.json` but no luck. Adding a build stage which calls `npm install` before deployment also does not work

Update 3: After adding `npm install` build stage, I am able to see that the dependencies have been successfully built via the logs. However, the require is not defined error still persists.

Update 4: Trying npm install from my CLI doesn't work as well even though all packages and dependencies are present

Update 5: Running `cf restage` or configuring cache via `cacheDirectories` does not work as well

Opened a related question regarding deployment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252968/cloud-foundry-folder-structure-and-relative-paths)

Comment: What is your package.json? Are you using the IDE with git and are all the changes committed?

Comment: yeap, it's connected to git with deployment being automated once changes are committed. I've been playing around with `module.exports` and it's also showing up as module is not defined. I'm guessing it's got to do with how it is being wrapped?

Comment: Add details to the question.

Comment: Oh finally, saw the edit/delete buttons. Added to question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found out my confusion was caused due to me not realizing that `require()` cannot be used on the client side unless via tools such as Browserify.