# Cloud Foundry - Folder structure and relative paths

Tags: node.js, ide, cloud, cloud-foundry

This is somewhat related to an issue I'm having with CF on IBM Cloud [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213650/node-package-dependencies-on-ibm-cloud-foundry-require-module-is-not-defined). My question after playing around with the folder structures is how exactly is CF building the app when it comes to relative paths?

For example, if i have the following folder structure

[image: folder structure]

when I add `<script type = 'text/javascript' src = '../index.js'></script>` to the `index.html` file, I get `GET https://simple-toolchain-20190320022356947.mybluemix.net/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`. This error does not happen when I move `index.js` into the `public` folder and change `<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'index.js'></script>`.

The problem I have then is that when I try to `require()` any modules when the `index.js` file is in a sub-directory, it returns a `Require is not defined` error indicating that it is not getting the module from the `node_modules` cache which CF is suppose to build. Requiring any files in the same sub-directory also throws the same error. This does not seem to be a problem when the `require()` is used in the default `app.js` as the application loads without any errors.

I'm relatively new to the IBM Cloud Foundry tool but I'm following the same structure as when I pushed apps via Cloud9 IDE and didn't have any such issues there. I feel I might be missing something ridiculously simple like configuration of endpoint or package.json. However, I've been searching around for days and can't seem to find a solution.

Appreciate if you have any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a Cloud Foundry question, but with Node.js. How much experience do you have with Node.js?

Comment: I have a basic understanding of Node.js but not good enough to solve this ;). The thing I'm confused about is that on my local desktop, as long as i `npm i {package}`, I am able to `require('{package}')` in any subdirectories. I only get errors when trying to migrate it to Cloud Foundry hence why I thought it is related to how CF builds the application.

Comment: I would recommend to start here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/index.html Cloud Foundry uses buildpacks for the supported languages, Node.js is one of them. See the info about package.json

Comment: Thx for the pointers especially clarifying that this is a node question. After searching some more, I found out the problem was that I was trying to use `require()` on the client side hence my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my lack of understanding, I was trying to use `require()` on the client side hence the errors. Going to figure out how to use Browserify now. ;)